# Trying to figureout specific Regex pattern for csv validation

Tags: regex, csv

I'm trying to work on a regex pattern that matches a word, or set of words within quotes like:

`"keyword"` OR `"keyword1 keyword2"`

And or either of the above that ends in a tilde & a number.

`"keyword"~3` OR `"keyword1 keyword2"~5`

But does not contain a third double quote within the keyword, or a double set of tilde's / numbers

Would Fail: `"keyword1" keyword2"` , `"keyword"~3~3`

So far I have this: [`^(\[\"\](\[^\"\'\]*)\[\"\])|(\"(\[^\"\'\]*)\"~\d)$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/hA8eI5/1)

However, `[^\"]` does not seem to be failing on the middle quote like I expect, and anything additional on the end seems to be passing as well...

Any advice on how I can make this more precise?

Comment: Is it JSON? Or is it CSV? Either way, it's not a job for regex.

Comment: I'm trying to parse a CSV file on this site: http://csvlint.io/validation/562ee9e8637376259d00002f

the regex pattern is for the schema which is wrote in json.

Comment: It's unclear which stage of processing you are in. Are you at the stage where you have parsed the CSV and want to validate each of the fields, or are you going to validate the lines as is? Also, include the sample input in the question, don't link it elsewhere.

Comment: What about `^"[^'"]+"(?:~\d)?$`: https://regex101.com/r/mW9aK8/2

Comment: This looks good within the regex tool, but is failing in their app, going to have to play with it some more. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: This worked for me: [validation](http://csvlint.io/validation/562f085563737608e700006c) [schema](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nauzilus/c4c56516fe9381b4584d/raw/00eb5173c0fadce2675fbaa75e520e00bb939fbf/schema.json) [csv](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nauzilus/c4c56516fe9381b4584d/raw/00eb5173c0fadce2675fbaa75e520e00bb939fbf/input.csv)

Comment: Looks to me like the regex is supposed to match just one field.  If that's the case, you shouldn't be using anchors at all.

Comment: @AlanMoore the schema defines per-field validation, so a regex is applied to a single field value. Anchors will ensure the field value matches exactly how you want.

Comment: @DanielFlint: I did a little digging, and it seems I misspoke. Instead of saying you *shouldn't* add anchors, I should have said you *can't* add them; they don't exist.  See my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is failing because your regex is being treated like so:

`^([\"]([^\"\']*)[\"])` OR `(\"([^\"\']*)\"~\d)$`

That is, must start with X or end with Y.

If you have a field in your CSV as `"this "should fail"`, it will match the first part of your regex, because it the meta-character `$` isn't associated with it, and therefore pass validation.

If you surround the entire regex in parentheses (excluding the start/end anchors), it should work:

`^(([\"]([^\"\']*)[\"])|(\"([^\"\']*)\"~\d))$`

Then it will be treated as the entire input must match X or must Y entirely.

Or this simpler version should also work: `^"[^'"]*"(~\d)?$`.

Comment: Thanks @Danial Flint - Was going to try this out, this morning but the csvlint service seems to be having load issues this morning and It wont return anything at the moment... Will accept an answer once I can get their tool to accept a schema.

Comment: Thanks so much this pointed me in the right direction, I ended up with the final regex of: `^(\"[^\"]*\"(?:~\d)?|\"[^\"]*\"(?:~\\d)?\\sAND\\s\"[^\"]*\"(?:~\\d)?)$`

Note I discovered I needed to double escape my \d as \\d for it to work with CSV Lint, that is what was causing my problems the whole time. 

Here is my final schema and an example file that works on csv lint: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2177583/csv/untitled.json
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2177583/csv/untitledUpload.csv

Comment: Glad you got that working! Note that escaping `\d` as `\\d` is actually to do with JSON, not CSV Lint itself. If you put in your JSON `\d` you're saying you literally want the `d` (which of course is the same without the escaping \\). It's the \ that needs escaping - you literally want a backslash - so it needs a double backslash.

Comment: That makes sense, I had not thought that at first and it was causing me some trouble, its been working great since then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of those anchors. The CSV schemas used on that site are descended from the W3C's XML Schema standard, which specifies its own regex flavor.  Commonly known as the XSD flavor, it's based on the Perl 5 flavor, but it supports only a tiny subset of the features available in Perl and most of its other derivatives.

One of those missing features is anchors.  In the XSD flavor, all matches are implicitly anchored at both ends.  That may sound terribly limiting, but it isn't.  You can always "pad" a match by adding `.*` to the ends, like you do with Java's `matches()` method.  But where `matches()` lets you add explicitly anchors anyway, XSD doesn't.  Outside of a character class, `^` and `$` are just normal characters.

That aside, the regex you're looking for is pretty simple:

```
"[^"]+"(?:~\d+)?
```

I updated your **[fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/hA8eI5/2)** to demonstrate.  Note that I used anchors in the fiddle, but you should not.  That was a workaround because Regex101 doesn't have a setting for pretending each line is a standalone string, like some other tools do.  I added the line separators in `[^"\r\n]` for the same reason; you probably won't need them.

Comment: That's good to know about XSD implicitly anchoring. CSVLint don't appear to do this though: [validation](http://csvlint.io/validation/562f43a2637376259d00006f), [schema](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nauzilus/640943a25e21bb64f98d/raw/0ed2a9fe1871d7c68d2294cff9d19c55bf7142c8/schema.json), [input](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nauzilus/640943a25e21bb64f98d/raw/0ed2a9fe1871d7c68d2294cff9d19c55bf7142c8/input.csv). e.g. pattern `foo` passes even if the literal value contains extra characters, e.g. `foobar`.

Comment: Apparently they use csvlint.rb, which just takes the pattern straight from the schema and matches the value against it: https://github.com/theodi/csvlint.rb/blob/8a6dea7f24ffe7fae9636d4b5976037f222150d1/lib/csvlint/field.rb#L51